# Invalid filename word exportasfixedformat

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use a mainly recorded macro to save selected text and the filename should be the headline. I tried following code:

```
Sub Makro5()

Dim flnNm As String

Selection.Copy
Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "\\ess\Shared Folders\V3\Handuch\"
'    flnNm = "PROZESSE"
flnNm = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=flnNm, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

When I type directly the name like in the commented line (flnNm) everything is OK. But when I try to use the text of the paragraph i get the error message: Invalid filename -2147467259 (80004005). 
When I debug the macro the content of flnNm seems OK.

Comment: What **is** the content of `flnNm` when it crashes?  Have you tried creating a file with that name manually?

Comment: @YowE3K: It depends on the content of the header. When I use the same chapter flnNm contains PROZESSE as it should, but I can't see if it contains e.g. additional invisible chars. To make it clear when I use the commented line it works and creates the file, when I use range.text it crashes.

Comment: There are rather invalid characters in filename (`flnNm`). Try to define file name in another way.